# How to put Webp images in a PDF with itext in java?

Tags: java, image, pdf, itext

I have a zip file that contains images with Webp extension, I have load them in an array on byte[].
When I try to add that image in the pdf an exception is throwen that says **The byte array is not a recognized imageformat**, does itext not support Webp image ?

```
public byte[] generatePdfById(String uuid) {
    try {
        log.info("Generate document for id {} ", uuid);
        PointDao ptDao = pointRepository.getById(uuid);
        Document document = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        List<byte[]> images = storedService.getBucketZipByKey(ptDao.getImageZip(), "images");
        byte[] firstImage = images.get(0);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(firstImage);
        document.open();
        document.add(image);
        document.close();
        byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new PtRuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Comment: What PDF library are you using? I don't think PDF natively supports embedding WebP, so the files need to be converted. Unfortunately, support for WebP in Java isn't that good yet, but there are some options. jDeli (commercial), TwelveMonkeys ImageIO* (open source, supports lossy only). *) I'm the developer/maintainer. 

Comment: I'm using itextpdf version 5.5.13.2

Answer (score 1):

The PDF standard currently doesn't list WebP among the permissible formats for encoding images in PDF documents. In other words, even if iText (or any other PDF library, really) would support directly including WebP content in its PDF output, PDF viewers out there wouldn't be able to display it anyhow.

Long story short, you'll need to convert the file to some other format (like PNG or JPG) first. :)

Comment: Maybe you have an idea how to produce multi-page document (not necessarily PDF) out of series of WEBP images without recompressing them?

Comment: I can't speak for non-PDF formats, but the "without recompressing them" part of your requirement wouldn't be achievable in PDF since the codecs for it aren't supported right now. There's some research ongoing in ISO working groups to extend 2D image format support, but I don't know off the top of my head whether WebP is being considered. Regardless, the outcome of that won't be relevant for end users until several years from now.

Are WebP images allowed in ePub? If so, that's another avenue to check.

Comment: @mval Could you share a link to an official website/documentation where the "permissible formats for encoding images in PDF documents" are listed?

Comment: PDF is standardised as ISO 32000, with ISO 32000-1 corresponding to PDF 1.7, and ISO 32000-2 corresponding to PDF 2.0. The former is freely available (see e.g. here: https://www.pdfa.org/resource/pdf-specification-index/). Regarding image codecs, not much changed between 1.7 and 2.0 AFAIK, so using the older spec as a reference should be OK. The stuff you want is mostly in clauses 7.4 and 8.9. You might also be interested in this status update: https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf-issues/discussions/248#discussioncomment-4244510.

Comment: "PNG or JPG" ... or SVG (vector graphic), and then render the SVG to PDF. for example, inkscape has a "trace bitmap" feature, see also [How do I convert a PNG to SVG?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470495/how-do-i-convert-a-png-to-svg)